# RegEx to match 2 digits before the dot and one digit after the dot(just 0 or 5)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression that will match one or two digits before the dot and one digit after the dot (0 or 5).

I tried it out for at least one hour, and I'm getting mad....

Possible results should be:

```
5,0
5,5
30,0
30,5 etc.
```

If just one digit is insert, it want a result as follows :

5 --> 5,0

Is there someone who can help me? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You just want to check for one or two digits, followed by the dot literal, and either '0' or '5'.

```
^\d{1,2}\.[05]$
```

That doesn't handle the single digit one, though. There's not an easy way to just match a single digit in the same regex you're matching one or two, so you could use a second regex:

```
^\d$
```

Then convert that to a double/float if you get any matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex...

> (?:\d{1,2}(?=.)|(?<=.)[50])

Answer (score 0):

```
string regex=@"(?<b>\d{1,2})(?<a>[.]0|[.]5)?";
Match m=Regex.Match(input,regex);
string result=m.Groups["b"].Value+","+m.Groups["a"].Value==""?0:m.Groups["a"].Value;
```

---

Above code would give these results for input

```
550.57 => 50,5    
644 => 44,0
```